# EC2 is dead after doing eth0 down

Tags: amazon-ec2

Thanks to my stupidity, I did this on an EC2 instance:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

After this, my instance became non-responsive and I don't see a way to bring the eth0 up. I was not able to SSH to the instance, nor change the ENI (I never provisioned a spare ENI in the VPC). The only option that was available was to terminate the instance. Now, I understand I can attach another ENI to the instance (eth1). What I want to understand is:

1. If eth0 is down, can the instance be still functional or bootable using eth1 (considering the instance was served with two eth* at the launch)?
2. Will the eth1 keep changing the private IP considering it was a secondary ENI?

Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stop/start the instance. As long as you didn't permanently disable eth0, it should come up with its normal configuration when the server starts again.

Comment: Awesome! That solved my issue!!